# Azure Active Directory account ownership transfer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have an AAD multi tenant application set up and also multi tenant Native application. They are both production applications. I am planning Azure account ownership transfer (transfer subscription) to another account. Any ideas if the applications and the AAD transfers OK? I cannot have a downtime and the Client IDs, App ID URI, Reply URL and redirect URIs cannot change. Is this expected to transfer smoothly just by using the Transfer Subscription in the Azure portal billing section?

Answer (score 1):

**Transferring an Azure subscription should have no effect on anything in your Azure Active Directory.**

When you transfer an Azure subscription you might be changing the Azure Active Directory it is associated with, however no change is made to the entities (users, groups, applications) in the Azure Active Directory itself.

As per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer#frequently-asked-questions-faq), the impact will be on your Azure subscription: your user/group assignments to resource groups will not be transferred.

That all being said, as with anything production related, you should always err on the side of caution and **do your own verification/testing on a test environment**.